# Lead Custom Field Mapping Failing

Tags: custom-field, lead-conversion, field-mapping

I'm working with a client on a project and have encountered some very strange behavior with custom lead field mapping upon lead conversion. I've created two custom fields on Lead and Account, both called Domain__c.

On Leads, this is a formula that returns text:
[image]

On Accounts, it is simply a text field:
[image]

I have set up the custom field mapping:
[image]

I would expect this to carry over to the account when converting a lead. However, when creating a test record, I can see the field is populated correctly on the lead:
[image]

However, when I convert the lead (and create a new account in the process), this value does not get mapped correctly to the Account:
[image]

Am I taking crazy pills? What am I missing here that is causing this mapping to fail? I've done this exact same thing in previous organizations, and I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: are you sure you don't have a `Domain` field (non-formula) also on Lead?  My experience is that formula fields can't be mapped on Lead Conversion (at least, not directly)

Comment: Yes I'm sure there isn't another domain field that I'm unintentionally mapping. Also, as I mentioned, I've done this exact same mapping in previous organizations so I don't think it's a limitation of not being able to map formula fields.

Comment: @ToddSprinkel, I tried to replicate this in my org and it worked perfectly. Lead formula field is mapped with Account textfield. I believe, you are checking with the correct Account record as it is named with "Test". Sometimes, we create so many test records with the same name and make a mistake.

Comment: I'm working in a fresh developer org, and there are only two accounts in the system (with different names) so this is not a case of checking the wrong test record.

Comment: Todd - well, I learned something new today re: formula fields and mapping. Not sure how I missed this before -- thanks.  As for your issue, I'm assuming you've looked for triggers/workflows on Account that inadvertently clear `Account.Domain__c`

Comment: @Devendra In your org, do you have the lead setting "Require validation for Converted Leads" checked? This is the only difference I can think of between the two orgs (one where it works, one where it does not) I've attempted this with. Salesforce support has so far not been helpful.

Comment: @ToddSprinkel I can see "Require Validation for Converted Leads" setting in my org and it is enabled.

Comment: It seems like this setting may be important in being able to map formula fields to text fields upon lead conversion. That said, I went with the obvious workaround of populating a plain-text field on leads via a workflow rule field update and mapping that to the account field.